# Configuring ejabberd + BOSH + HTTP Binding + Candy.js

Tags: proxy, nginx, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to get the [Candy.js](http://amiadogroup.github.com/candy/) example to connect to a locally installed ejabberd server that I have configured according to [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/272956).

I know nginx is proxying correctly because I can navigate to the URL I specified in the nginx configuration file and the ejabberd HTTP binding placeholder page will display correctly.

I can also connect and log into to the ejabberd server normally through an XMPP client like Pidgin. Pidgin will also connect over BOSH perfectly fine when I specify the BOSH URL in the account setup.

When I login with Candy.js with debugging turned on, it tells me it has actually logged in successfully.  It then returns a 504 error. I can also look at the ejabberd "online users" page and it will confirm that I am logged in.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I get the Candy.js example page working correctly?

Comment: You still need help with this? I see it never got answered :)